# Does usage of keywords in multiple <p><div> cause keyword stuffing?

Tags: keyword-stuffing

Does the usage of keywords in multiple `<p><div>` cause keyword stuffing? If so, what should be the keyword density?

I see most websites ranking at the top for few search terms have a density of more than 4-5%.

Comment: I don't think the `<p><div>` tags matter.  It's always about your content.  Do your keywords occur naturally, or are you/they trying to trick the search engine?  Websites that rank because of keyword stuffing, don't always keep their rank, but pages that answer the user's query slowly rise to the top.

Comment: Welcome to webmasters! Search is not about keywords contrary to what the SEOs tell you. It is about whole language. As well keyword density is a myth and has never been true. You have to understand that SEO sites are largely written by people who do not understand the technology used in search and often find correlation and assume causation. As well, many parrot the thoughts of others on their site as a "me too" trying to get a slice of the SEO traffic pie. Create content for people and not for machines and do not worry too much. Your site will perform as it should. Cheers!!